Dirichlet Jordan test for Fourier series in n dimensions
I saw the Dirichlet Jordan test results for $n$ dimension Fourier Transform in this paper
https://www.ams.org/journals/proc/2001-129-04/S0002-9939-00-05658-6/S0002-9939-00-05658-6.pdf
The results can be formulated as follows
\begin{equation}
\widehat{f}(\xi)=(2\pi)^{-n/2}\int f(x)e^{-i\xi x}dx,\quad S_Rf(x)=(2\pi)^{-n/2}\int_{|\xi|<R} \widehat{f}(\xi)e^{i\xi x}d\xi
\end{equation}
It seems that the paper shows that
\begin{equation}
\lim_{R\rightarrow\infty} S_Rf(x)=\tilde{f}(x),\quad \tilde{f}(x_0)=\lim_{r\rightarrow 0}\frac{1}{V_nr^n}\int_{|y|<r} f(x_0+y)dy
\end{equation}
Can these results be applied to Fourier series in $n$ dimension? Specifically does the limit in the second equation also holds for finite Fourier series $S^*_Rf(x)$ with
\begin{equation}
S^*_Rf(x)=\sum_{|\xi|_\infty<R}\widehat{f}(\xi)e^{i\xi x},\quad \xi_i=2\pi n_i/L
\end{equation}
for example?

Hi, please rewrite the results in question in your post so that more answer can be written for you !
